# npx create-express-api keeps getting unknown errors

Tags: node.js, git, npm, package, npx

I keep getting errors on CMD when I try to use `create-express-api` for somewhat reasons.

Launched by `git CMD`:

```
Cloning into 'server'...

events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn rm ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:273:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn rm',
  path: 'rm',
  spawnargs: [ '-rf', 'server/.git' ]
}
```

Launched by `Powershell`:

```
fatal: destination path 'server' already exists and is not an empty directory.

events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn rm ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:273:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn rm',
  path: 'rm',
  spawnargs: [ '-rf', 'server/.git' ]
}
```

I have downloaded all the softwares & control systems that make running the package, `npm`, `npx`, `git` and also downloaded `npm i create-express-api`.

```
npm -v: 6.14.6
npx -v: 6.14.6
git --version: git version 2.28.0.windows.1
```

Why can't I use the package by using `npx` command?

Any solutions?

Comment: Have you tried to use 
# with global install 
```create-express-api name-of-app```
# with npx 
```npx create-express-api name-of-app```

Comment: @gunblades like this? `npm i # create-express-api` & `npx # create-express-api server`

Comment: I've add an answer, could you check that?

Answer (score 0):

So I've tried in my machine... I do the following:

```
npx create-express-api name-of-app
```

And everything goes right. I could open the folder `name-of-app` and ran `npm run dev` and worked

---

Another try is install global and run:

```
npm install -g create-express-api
create-express-api name-of-app
```

---

The last way is to clone the repository manually and install its dependencies

```
git clone https://github.com/w3cj/express-api-starter.git server
cd server
npm install
```

Comment: I tried both attempts. The first one still won't work. The CMD throws the same errors. The second one throws another error when I type `create-express-api name-of-app` after installed the package globally.

Comment: This is the error from second attempt: `File C:\Users\myPCname\AppData\Roaming\npm\create-express-api.ps1 cannot be loaded because
running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ create-express-api server`

Comment: It's so weird. I've cleared my PC completely for running this command w/o any crashes from the other apps. But it never works.

Comment: Could you try to execute the command in admin console?

Comment: Still won't work. Both CMD throws the same errors what I got before, git CMD and Powershell.

Comment: could you try to run in powershell console the following: 
``Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`` and then ``create-express-api name-of-app``

Comment: It says the file already exists: `fatal: destination path 'server' already exists and is not an empty directory.

events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn rm ENOENT`

Comment: Let's try the following, delete the folder called ``server`` then in a powershell console ``Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`` and so ``create-express-api server``

Comment: When I remove the `server` file and retry it, It creates the folder and files. However, it still throws this error: `events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: spawn rm ENOENT . . .` which is the same error from the first try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219155/discussion-between-gunblades-and-sniffingdoggo).